# Deriving an expression for reaction time in terms of the total concentration

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

> Consider the dimerization of protein $\ce{A}:$
>
> $$\ce{2A <=> A2}$$
>
> with forward rate constant $k_1$ and backwards rate constant $k_{-1}.$ Derive the following expression for the reaction time in terms of the total concentration of protein
>
> $$\frac{1}{\tau^2} = k^2_\mathrm b + 8k_\mathrm ak_\mathrm b[\ce{A}]_t,$$
>
> where $[\ce{A}]_t = [\ce{A}] + 2[\ce{A2}].$

I assumed the 1st order in the forward direction and the 2nd order in the reverse direction. Rate law:

$$-\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm dt} = k_1[\ce{A}]^2 - k_{-1}[\ce{A2}].\tag{1}$$

At equilibrium

$$k_1[\ce{A}]^2_\mathrm{eq} - k_{-1}[\ce{A2}]_\mathrm{eq} = 0.\tag{2}$$

I then substituted that into the rate law and factored out the rate constants with the aim of getting rid of all of the equilibrium concentrations. The equation indicates that

$$\frac{-1}{2}\frac{-\mathrm d[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm dt} = \frac{-\mathrm d[\ce{A_2}]}{\mathrm dt} \quad\implies\quad \frac{\mathrm d[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm dt} = -2\frac{\mathrm d[\ce{A2}]}{\mathrm dt}.\tag{3}$$

I then got stuck. I saw something where you define a displacement variable $x$ and then try to get the rate law in terms of $x,$ but I've tried that approach and keep running into dead ends.

Comment: For formatting, See [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) and [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here?noredirect=1&lq=1). For a more detailed MathJax guide, look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [minor other details](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: In my opinion, there is no "reaction time" for this equilibrium. An equilibrium needs an infinite amount of time to be attained.

Comment: Just for fun, you can compute the time integral of (1) and substitute $\tau$ for the end time.Than you will see the final relation of reaction quotient Q and K.

Comment: What are $k_a$ and $k_b$?

Comment: Let the amount of $A_2=x$ and write down $dA_2/dt=dx/dt=2k_1[A]^2-k_{-1}[A_2]$ and find x the amount reacted in terms of $[A_0]$ and $[A]$ and substitute into the equation. Separate variables, ie, integrate in $x$ and $t$ separately. The integral in $x$ is just horrid but look for the constant square root term in front of the log terms.   This is equivalent to $ 1 / \tau ^2$. If $[A_0]$ is the initial A I found $1/\tau^2=4k_1k_{-1}[A_0]+k_{-1}^2$ which is related to your answer. (btw. should your $[A]_t=2[A]+[A_2]$ )

Comment: No I'm pretty sure the total [A] is correct. My professor literally copied and pasted it out of  our physical chemistry textbook

Comment: @Maurice the relaxation is first order (or pseudo first) and as such has a well defined lifetime or characteristic rate constant. The general solution is of the form $\ln( f(k,c))=-w(k)t$ where $f(k,c)$ is some (usually complicated) function of rate constants and concentrations and  $w(k)$ a function of rate constants and *initial* concentrations so has a constant value so that $1/\tau\equiv w(k)$.